# Calling a function exported from C (swig interface) from C#

Tags: c#, c, xamarin.ios, swig

I have a function in C language with definition like

```
uint8 *callme (uint8 a, uint8 b, uint8 c)
```

In interface.i file I have defined function as

```
%module abc
%{
.... C Header files (.h)
%}
extern void uint8 *callme (uint8 a, uint8 b, uint8 c);
```

I have generated .a file with XCode Cocoa touch library and .dll file from generated .cs files.

I am trying to call this callme function from my C# code in Xamarin iOS app.
But I am not sure how to pass the value to this function. Every time I am getting error as **"Cannot convert from datatype to abc.SWIGTYPE_p_uint8"**

Answer (score 0):

Every type for which SWIG creates a *SWIGTYPE_p_** is a type that is not understood by SWIG.

You need to look arround [Typemaps](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Typemaps).

You have some example of C# typemaps in the typemaps.i you can find in [swig_file]/lib/csharp.

When you will have the correct typemaps for an uint8, your problem should be fixed.